# MD5 on a concatenation of strings in postgresql 8

Tags: amazon-redshift, md5

I am trying to create a MD5 hash on the concatenation of two strings in PostgreSQL 8.0.2 :

```
SELECT MD5('12345' || '2022-11-24 17:27:10.535106+00');
```

But I have the error :

```
ERROR:  type " " does not exist
```

How can I apply MD5 on a concatenation of strings ?

Comment: I think you have some strange whitespace characters in your code. Try `MD5('12345'||'2022-11-24 17:27:10.535106+00')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm in redshift which is a fork of postgresql 8.0.2, select version(); gives me PostgreSQL 8.0.2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name indeed copy pasting your strings works :'D